# C++ Header files for shared library, which headers to install? (best practice)

Tags: c++, deployment, installation, shared-libraries, header-files

When creating a shared C++ library, what is best practice for installing header files?  More specifically, I have the following two questions:

1. I am working on a shared library project with headers which have complex interdependencies, so do I simply install them all, or is there a way of restricting the number of headers needed?
2. I plan to install headers to a subdirectory of e.g. /usr/local/include to avoid polluting the top level directory, is this the right thing to do?

Other info: I only really want to provide an interface to the library. The project is an autotools project and I am using the `pkginclude_HEADERS` command in my Makefile.am files to install the headers in the appropriate subdirectory. I am actually converting this project from a program that used static libraries, to a shared library and small program that links to the library. People are unlikely to use just a small part of the library rather than the whole thing.

Edit:

In response to a vote to close for being opinion based, I would also consider a valid answer that this is purely project-specific, or down to taste, and there is no accepted best practice, but I doubt this to be the case, or I would not have asked.

Answer (score 4):

One common approach is to put public header files in a `include` directory and the rest of the  source files (both hpp and cpp) in a `src` directory. For example, suppose you're working on a  project called `foo`. A possible file hierarchy would be the following:

```
foo
    include
        foo
            x.hpp
            y.hpp
    src
        x.cpp
        y.cpp
        z.cpp
        z.hpp
```

In this case, you can simply add the `include` directory to the include path and you'll then be able to include the public header files like this: `#include <foo/x.hpp>`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, but are you referring to when the files are installed on a system? My question is about installation of header files for the library (e.g. in `/usr/local/include`), not the organisation in my sources (autotools can put things wherever I tell it to when I run `make install`). Sorry if I've misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my ideas while I am not sure if I have the right answer:).

A:

1. If the headers have complex inter-dependencies, it will be safer to simply install them all. Or you might want to read the source codes and clean the inter-dependencies.
2. It is the right thing to put all the headers in one discretionary. :)